# Flutter Project Kotlin Gradle Plugin Error in Android Emulator: How to Resolve?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, emulation

I am working on a Flutter project that functions well on the web, but when I attempted to run it on the Android emulator, I encountered an error: "[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update." I have checked and updated to the latest version, but the issue persists. I had resolved this error before, but it reoccurs whenever I add new dependencies. I have tried various solutions I came across, but none have proven effective in correcting this issue.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried updating the Kotlin Gradle plugin to the latest version as suggested by the error message. Additionally, I have explored various online solutions such as checking for compatibility issues with Flutter dependencies, ensuring the correct version of Kotlin is specified in the project, and updating the project's build files.

I was expecting these steps to resolve the issue and allow me to run the Flutter project on the Android emulator without encountering the Kotlin Gradle plugin error. However, despite these efforts, the problem persists, especially when I add new dependencies to the project.